# SCSS file compiled result is not added to custom _document js file. NEXTJS

Tags: next.js

I'm having a problem when I try to use scss with a custom '_document.js' file.

The compiled result is not beeing added as a stylesheet link.

Here's '_document.js' file

```
import Document, { Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang='es' dir='ltr'>
        <head>
          <meta charSet='utf-8' />
          <link
            rel='stylesheet'
            href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i,700,700i'
          />
        </head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomDocument
```

I'm using @zeit/next-sass and node-sass.
Here's my next.config.js file

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass()
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to add some config?

Thanks!!

Comment: I've tried linking this ' _next/static/style.css ', and doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you import your global scss file file in pages/_app.js ? If you don't have pages/_app.js you should import it separately on top of all the files in pages folder.

If you are using NextJS > 9.3 you now have built in support for SCSS. You can remove the next.config.js and add the setup as mentioned in the link below.

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#built-in-sass-support-for-global-stylesheets